# for loop is not giving expected output in sh whereas it is working fine if sh """#!/bin/bash +x is added to the script block

Tags: bash, shell, sh

```
for newfile in `find . -type f ! -path "./data/*" ! -name new_changes.txt`; do 
     if ! grep -q "\$newfile" new_changes.txt; then 
       rm \$newfile;
     fi
done
```

The above code works fine if `sh """#!/bin/bash +x` is given at the starting of the code block. But when it is commented out - It throws the below error

> rm: cannot remove '$newfile': No such file or directory

Any suggestions on how we can modify this for loop to work without `sh """#!/bin/bash +x`?

Comment: try `rm ${newfile}`

Comment: The braces are optional and `$newfile` will also work. But having the backslash means that it will look for a literal `$` character, which is the opposite of what is intended here. What is happening with the `sh " ...` etc is that it is evaluating a string in which `\$` becomes just `$` and then putting it back through the interpreter again, after which the variable substitution happens as intended.

Comment: Thank you @DigvijayS and alaniwi- That worked!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@alaniwi already explained in his comment the error in your `rm` command. You are trying to remove a file with the name `$newfile`, and you probably don't have any file starting with a Dollar sign.

The other problem is similar, but not identical: Your `grep`  command searches for a **literal** string `$newfile`, while you probably want to search for a string stored in the **variable** newfile. Hence you have to drop the `\`.

But this still means that the content of the variable `newfile` is subject to interpretation as a regular expression. For example, if `newfile` has the value `abc.txt`, `grep` would also succeed if  `new_changes.txt` contained just `abcdtxt`. To avoid this error, you should use the `-F` option to grep, to avoid interpretation as a regexp.

And still, there is one more error: Say `newfile` has the value `abc`, and `new_changes.txt` contained just `xxxabc`, but they would still match, since `abc` is a substring of `xxxabc`. To avoid this error, you should use the `-x` option to grep, which forces to match the whole line.

Hence, your command should be `grep -qFx "$newfile" new_changes.txt`